# Lua random number to the 8th decimal place

Tags: lua

How do I get a random number in Lua to the eighth decimal?

Example : 0.00000001

I have tried the following and several variations of this but can not get the format i need.

```
math.randomseed( os.time() )
x = math.random(10000000,20000000) * 0.00000001
print(x)
```

i would like to put in  say 200 and get this  0.00000200

Comment: Are you looking for help generating a random number or formatting a number once you get it?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grab a random number from 0-9, and slide it down 6 places. You can use format specifiers to create the string representation of the number that you desire. For floats we use `%f`, and indicate how many decimal places we want to have with an intermediate `.n`, where `n` is a number.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
-- random(9) to exclude 0
print(('%.8f'):format(math.random(0, 9) * 1e-6))
--> '0.00000400'
```

Comment: Might want to use `* 1e-6` instead of `/ math.pow(10, 6)`.

Comment: thank you...  i did have to make a few changes because my question was not exactly what i wanted till i saw your help.   i will mark it correct because it got me where i needed and i will update my question accordingly to what i got to with your help

Answer (score 1):

string.format("%.8f",math.random())

Answer (score -1):

to help anyone else.   my question should have been worded a bit better.   i wanted to be able to get random numbers and get it to the 8th decimal place.

but i wanted to be able to have those numbers  from 1-10,000  so he is updated how i wanted it and the help of Oka  got me to this

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
lowest = 1
highest = 7000
rand=('%.8f'):format(math.random(lowest, highest) / 100000000)
print(rand)
```

Hope this helps someone else   or if it can be cleaned up  please let me know